# is it possible to share usb devices over hub using usb-ip?

Tags: linux, usb, virtualization

I want to share my USB security dongle remotely over hub. So it could be shared with another Windows PC. I tried `usbip` but seems like usb sharing device will act as a server and not as a hub. Is there any workaround so I could remotely attach my usb security dongle over hub and share it with another windows PC ?

Updated : i was looking for something similar to flexihub where user share device remotely over a hub between two windows pc.

Comment: It would be better if you shared the source that shows how you tried to share the dongle remotely over hub.  [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  Generally speaking, I have my doubts this is a valid thing to do with a security dongle.  The more pieces of software and hardware between a dongle and the software that is querying the dongle, the more susceptible it is to a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: @DanielWisehart as i said i tried Usb-ip but the issue in  USB ip is that usbip server must be installed on linux and should had usb devices binded to that server. so i was thinking of a way where i could remotely bind my usb device(Dongle) over that linux usb-ip server remotely from windows pc 1 and attached(mount) that usb device(dongle) on windows pc 2 from linux server. if i am correct then this is something similar what **Flexihub** does